# Unable to get all files and folder under C:\windows\system32\OOBE folder structure

Tags: file, directory

below is the code which i have written. but getting only single and 2 DLL information only.

```
string[] allfiles = Directory.GetFiles("C:\\Windows\\System32\\oobe", "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);

foreach (var file in allfiles)
{
    FileInfo info = new FileInfo(file);
    listBox_DirectoryRecoveryOOBE.Items.Add(info);
}

DirectoryInfo directoryinfo = new DirectoryInfo("C:\\Windows\\System32");
DirectoryInfo[] dirs = directoryinfo.GetDirectories();

FileInfo[] WindowsSys32 = directoryinfo.GetFiles();


foreach (System.IO.DirectoryInfo di in dirs)
{
    listBox_DirectoryMainOOBE.Items.Add(di.FullName);
}

foreach (FileInfo fileinfo in WindowsSys32)
{
    listBox_DirectoryMainOOBE.Items.Add(fileinfo.FullName);
}
```

Comment: Have you debugged your code? What happened then? Your "question" is missing all essential parts

Comment: yes, its only give me very less results. can you please try my code and let me know the issue